# How do I replace the the character that the user enters with an "x" of the same index?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna write a code for a word guessing game, the player enters a character, if it exists in the word, an x of the same index gets replaced with the character.

JavaScript code:

```
var word = "hello"; // global variable

function hiddenWord() {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML += "";

    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML += "x";    
    }
}
function check() {
    var letter=document.getElementById("userInput").value; // the letter entered by the user
    var x=document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML; // the hidden word
    var y=word.search(letter);  

    x.replace(x.charAt(y),word.charAt(y));
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
 <form>
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1 id="txt"></h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="hiddenWord()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <td colspan="2"> <hr></td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="userInput">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="check" onclick="check()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: You can you [cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/) то format your inputs

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

**JavaScript:**

```
var word = "hello"; // global variable

function hiddenWord() {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML += "x";    
    }
    document.getElementById("userInput").focus();
}
function check() {
    var letter=document.getElementById("userInput").value; // the letter entered by the user
    var x = document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML; // the hidden word
    var y = word.search(letter);  
    if (y != -1) {
        for (var i = y; i < word.length; i++) {
            if (letter == word.slice(i, i + 1)) {
                  x = x.slice(0, i) + letter + x.slice(i + 1, x.length);
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = x;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
 <form>
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h1 id="txt"></h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="hiddenWord();" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <td colspan="2"> <hr></td>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="userInput">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="check" onclick="check();">
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</body>
```

**Some of the things I changed:**

- Added a closing `}` to the `check()` function
- Copied the changed word back into the `txt` element
- Made the `Click Me` button only add one set of X's, so if you click it multiple times you don't get multiple sets of X's
- added focus on the input box after the X's are shown

You could make the code more concise using a regex instead of the `for` loop, but I'm at work right now and don't have the time to do that here.

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` function returns a new string and does not modify the existing string. You would need to re-assign the returned value to `x`:

`x = x.replace(x.charAt(y),word.charAt(y));`

Moreover, `replace` only replaces the first instance. You would need to use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with a global switch to replace all instances:

`x = x.replace(new RegExp('x.charAt(y)', 'g'), word.charAt(y));`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working approach:

```js
// Replace char of string at given index
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, char) {
  "use strict";
  return this.substr(0, index) + char + this.substr(index + 1);
};

const secretWord = 'example';
let mask = new Array(secretWord.length + 1).join('x'); // As maxy 'x' chars as letters in constant 'secretWord'

function unmask(guess) {
  "use strict";
  for (let i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
    if (secretWord.charAt(i) === guess) {
      mask = mask.replaceAt(i, guess);
    }
  }
}

// Test
unmask('e');
unmask('a');
document.body.textContent = mask; // Should result in exaxxxe
```

- Constant `secretWord` contains word that is meant to be guessed. Variable `mask` contains as many 'x' characters as there are letters in constant `secretWord`.
- The function `unmask` takes one-character long parameter `guess` and it "uncovers that letter", i.e. it replaces those `x` characters of a mask that are at indexes, at which in constant `secretWord` you would find character specified by that parameter.
- Note, that with this approach guessing `x` character will not bring you expected results, but this is what you wanted. To solve this you can cover letters with some character that will never be present in string meant to be guessed, like for example `black square` Unicode character (■).